# Deriving an expression for $x(T)$, from $v(T)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

If I have that $$v(T)=\int_0^T\frac{F_x}{m}=\frac{F_0 T}{2m}.$$

Then shouldn't $$x(T)=\int_0^T\frac{F_0 T}{2m}=\frac{F_0 T}{2m}\int_0^T1=\frac{F_0 T^2}{2m},$$

*i.e* integrate $a$ to get $v$, integrate $v$ to get $x$. But the correct answer for $x(T)$ is given as $\frac{F_0 T^2}{3m}.$ Have I operated with false assumptions/integral application? Can someone help?

Comment: All integrals require an infinitesimal multiplier; in this case a "dt". It is preferable to use a different (but similar) symbol in the limits.

Comment: Your integrals have no differentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though there may be some information we're missing to get to the answer you are looking for. Was there an initial velocity that we're missing? Assuming that this is a constant force acting on a particle and it starts from $x=0$, then the velocity at any time $T$ is given by the integral,

$$ v(T)=\int_0^T a\,dt  = \int_0^T \frac{F}{m}\,dt = \frac{FT}{m} $$
Then assuming that the particle starts from rest i.e. $v_0=0$, we can find the position $x$ at any time $T$ by substituting $v(t)=\frac{Ft}{m}$ into an integration of velocity with respect to time.

$$ x(T) = \int^T_0 v(t)\, dt = \int^T_0 \frac{Ft}{m}\, dt = \frac{FT^2}{2m} $$

It seems that you did the integration incorrectly but still wound up with the right answer. If $\frac{FT^2}{3m}$ is indeed the answer you're seeking, please provide us with more information about the problem.

Comment: I don't think we can use definite integral for finding the velocity expression. If we use the definite integral,wouldn't it give the specific velocity at time $t=T$? Hence it is a number and integrating it would not give an expression for position?

Comment: You can absolutely use a definite integral in this sort of problem so long as you know what the velocity (and position) are at $t=0$, which I noted as assumptions. We are not plugging in a number for $T$. It's really just a dummy variable. I think arguing that $T$ is a number and not a variable is pedantic

Comment: I should mention, that this is a Pearson online problem.

Comment: @user140878 I don't have access to your Pearson account so I can't see the problem. Can you provide the full question?

Answer (score -1):

I think you misunderstood how to integrate. The variable you integrate the function $a$ is with respect to $T$.
Hence the integral would be:

$ v=\int a dT =\int \frac{F}{m} dT=\frac{F*T}{m}+C$

Where C is an arbitrary constant which states the inital velocity.

Then we need to integrate the result again by variable time T to get the position between, say, $T=0$ to $T=t$:
$ x=\int v dT =\int_{0}^{t} \frac{F*T}{m}+C dT=\frac{F*t^2}{3m}+C*t$

Comment: In physics integrals generally describe real situations which have limits and no constants of integration. (Limits were indicated in this problem.)

Comment: Noted. The integration limit is added to the final expression.

Comment: You don't need to use $*$ to indicate multiplication. Joined up writing is better, e.g. $Ft^2$.